# Obtener datos de una variable de JavaScript a php

Tags: javascript, php

(soy novato)

Disculpen tengo una variable en JavaScript que contiene un array que obtiene cuando se selecciona alguna opción de un select, pero no se como pasar esa variable de JavaScript que contiene los datos de js a php, para guárdalo en una variable de php.
Alguien me podría guiar como realizarlo.

La variable (js) que quiero pasarlo a php en una variable es esta `mis_consultas=todasConsultas[tiempos];`

////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////////

```
var consulta_1=new Array("WHERE dias = 0");
var consulta_2=new Array("WHERE dias between 1 and 2");
var consulta_3=new Array("WHERE dias between 3 and 4");
var consulta_4=new Array("WHERE dias >=5");
var consulta_5=new Array("WHERE dias <=-1");

var todasConsultas = [
  [],
  consulta_1,
  consulta_2,
  consulta_3,
  consulta_4,
  consulta_5
];

function cambia_consulta(){ 
   //tomo el valor del select del tiempo elegido 
   var tiempos 
   tiempos = document.form.tiempos[document.form.tiempos.selectedIndex].value 
   //miro a ver si el tiempo está definido 
   if (tiempos != 0) { 
      //si estaba definido, entonces coloco las opciones de la consulta correspondiente. 
      //selecciono el array de la consulta adecuado 
      mis_consultas=todasConsultas[tiempos];
      console.log(mis_consultas);
      //calculo el numero de la consulta 
      num_consultas = mis_consultas.length; 
      //marco el número de la consulta en el select 
      document.form.consulta.length = num_consultas
      //para cada consulta del array, la introduzco en el select 
      for(i=0;i<num_consultas;i++){ 
         document.form.consulta.options[i].value=mis_consultas[i] 
         document.form.consulta.options[i].text=mis_consultas[i] 

         $.post('prueba2.php',{
          consulta :mis_consultas
         })
         
      } 
   }else{ 
      //si no había consulta seleccionada, elimino las consulta del select 
      document.form.consulta.length = 1 ;
      //coloco un guión en la única opción que he dejado 
      document.form.consulta.options[0].value = "-" ;
      document.form.consulta.options[0].text = "-" ;
   } 
   //marco como seleccionada la opción primera de consulta 
   document.form.consulta.options[0].selected = true ;
}
```

Comment: Codigo como imagen no por favor. Agrega tu codigo con el boton '{ }'

Comment: La comunicación entre JavaScript y PHP se hace mediante llamadas [Ajax](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/Guide/AJAX). Recuerda que JavaScript se ejecuta en el lado cliente y PHP en el lado servidor. Saludos